# How to bind asp data table into string array in asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a java script, i want to bind  data table in variable available ?

```
<script>
   $(function () {
       *var available* = [

        ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
           source: availableTags
        });
   });
</script>
```

I have a data table which is as follows:-

```
ds = du.returnDataSet("proc", "SHOW_REFINE_SEARCH", Parameters, DbTypes, ParameterTypes, values, Lengths);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

the data table value comes in the form which are as follows:-

```
Zone_ID Zone_Name     Company_ID
1       Rajasthan          1
2       Madhya Pradesh     1
3       Maharashtra        1
4       Uttar Pradesh      1
5       Jammu and Kashmir  1
6       Gujarat            1
```

> I want to bind zone_name in javascript string variable...

Answer (score 1):

**Use Linq to DataTable** Use [.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
ds = du.returnDataSet("proc", "SHOW_REFINE_SEARCH", Parameters, DbTypes, ParameterTypes, values, Lengths);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables[0];
string[] zone_nameList = (from n in dt.AsEnumerable() select n.Filds<string>("zone_name")).ToArray();
```

Comment: how to append zone_namelist in javascript variable

Comment: @PraveenSingh - You have to use `WebMethod` for this

Answer (score 0):

There are other options with jQuery which you can use instead of using array you can use a web method.

You can go through this link

http://blog.nitinsawant.com/2011/09/integrating-jquery-ui-autocomplete-in.html

There are many question asked to SO all ready like

1. [Jquery autocomplete .NET WebMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762490/jquery-autocomplete-net-webmethod)
2. [Jquery AutoComplete with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680792/jquery-autocomplete-with-database)

You need to create a `web method` or `generic http handler` as use it as source for you auto complete.